# changing created on text in joomla 3

Tags: joomla, metadata, joomla3.4

I'm currently modifying the joomla 3 template for one of my homepages and I'm having trouble changing the created on text of featured articles.

you can see the text "AM 11. MAI 20015." in the screenshot.

[image]

I want to change it to "11. Mai 2015"

when i go to the Language override function and search for COM_CONTENT_PUBLISHED_DATE_ON it gives me a different text, even though there are no overrides yet, since it is a fresh install.

any help is appreciated.

John

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario - you could use Javascript to format the date how you want it displayed.

Best case scenario - depending on the template, the date might be getting formatted in the view.html file.  Check there to see if you can find where it's getting formatted and change it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `jlayout` for infoblock create_date you will see this

```
<dd class="create">
                    <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                    <time datetime="<?php echo JHtml::_('date', $displayData['item']->created, 'c'); ?>" itemprop="dateCreated">
                        <?php echo JText::sprintf('COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE_ON', JHtml::_('date', $displayData['item']->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'))); ?>
                    </time>
            </dd>
```

and you could change it to a different format. E.g. for English

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
```

Or you could override the language string for LC3 to match what you want.